# Method ambiguous when overloading with variable argument

Tags: java, overloading

I am a newcomer into Java. Today I saw a piece of code in "Thinking in Java", but I cannot figure out why it produce compile time error.

Code:

```
public class OverloadingVarargs2 {
    static void f(float i, Character... args) {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    static void f(Character... args) {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(1, 'a');
        f('a', 'b');
    }
}
```

Compile complained:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method f(float, Character[]) is ambiguous for the type OverloadingVarargs2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with `f('a', 'b');`

Both methods have a vararg argument, which means they will both be considered on the [third and final phase of overloading resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4).

`'a'` is a `char`, which can be automatically converted to `float` via [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Both `'a'` and `'b'` can be converted from `char` to `Character` using [Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Therefore both `f(float i, Character... args)` and `f(Character... args)` are applicable for the arguments `'a'` and `'b'`, and none of them has a precedence over the other.

Answer (score 6):

The statement `f('a', 'b');` is ambiguous, because the compiler cannot infer which exact method to invoke.

The reason behind this is that he `char` primitive type is considered as numeric (for each character there's a corresponding non-negative integer value between 0 and 65535).

That is why the compiler cannot infer if the parameter `'a'` stands for the integer value of `97`, which should be then cast to `float` *or* `'a'` stands for the character `'a'` which should be then autoboxed to `Character`.

Answer (score 3):

this causes trouble because

```
f('a', 'b');
```

`'a'` can be converted to int and hence passed to float in the first `f()`.